# Find Row Mismatch for Index

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a multi index pandas df that looks like the image below. The Group is the main index. Each group represents a group of duplicate files. The file number is a unique identifier for each file. Value 1 and Value 2 are metadata fields in this example.

What I would like to do is find instances where ANY metadata across a group is inconsistent.

For example, in the below image, Group 1 would return because File Numbers 1 and 2 in group A1 have differing metadata under 'Value 1' - so I would want that group to return. Group A2 on the other hand wouldn't return as the metadata IS consistent.

Is there a way to generate this dataframe?

df = pd.read_csv('files.csv', index_col = ['Group', 'File Number'])

[image: sample table]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `groupby_nunique` and broadcast the output to all rows. Finally, find rows where at least one value is not consistent:

```
out = df[df.groupby(level='Group').transform('nunique').ne(1).any(axis=1)]
print(out)

# Output
                  Value 1 Value 2
Group File Number                
A1    1                 A       C
      2                 B       C
```

**Update**

Solution inspired by @mozway [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73072432/15239951) using `filter` instead of `transform` and implicit `loc`:

```
out = df.groupby(level='Group').filter(lambda g: g.nunique().ne(1).any())
print(out)

# Output
                  Value 1 Value 2
Group File Number                
A1    1                 A       C
      2                 B       C
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `groupby` with [`nunique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nunique.html)

```
tuples = [('A1',1),('A1',2),('A2',3),('A2',4)]
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=["Group", "File Number"])
value1 = ['A','B','D','D']
df = pd.DataFrame(data=value1,index=index, columns=['Value1'])

df.groupby('Group').nunique()
```

Data frame:
[image]

Now, using `df.groupby('Group').nunique()`
gives

```
    Value1
Group   
A1  2
A2  1
```

Comment: The idea is interesting +1 :) You missed to use `transform` to broadcast this values to all rows. Check my answer.